# How many 4-digit odd numbers can be formed using the digits 0, 1, 2 and 3 only if the repetition of the digit is not allowed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, permutations, combinations

As stated in the title above: How many 4-digit odd numbers can be formed using the digits 0, 1, 2 and 3 only if the repetition of the digit is not allowed?

I already have the answer for this and it is 8.

(2)(2)(1)(2) = 8

However, I do not understand how it became like that. Any understandable explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: Well the last digit must be $1$ or $3$. That's a choice with $2$ options. You can put  the $0$ in the second or third place but not in the first or last place.  That's another choice with $2$ options. You have to two spaces left and two digits left.  So you have a choice for what to put in the first place and two options.  After that there are no more choices or options.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint #1**: Since the number is odd, then the unit's digit could only be either $1$ or $3$.

**Hint #2**: Since the number has $4$ digits, the thousand's digit cannot be $0$.

Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it.  There are $4!=24$ permutations of the $4$ digits.  Half of them end in $0$ or $2$, so only $12$ of them are odd. Since a four-digit number can't start with $0$ we must exclude the permutations that start with $0$.

Once we fix the last digit, there are three digits left, and one of them is $0$, so we exclude one third of the $12$ cases.  That leaves $12-4=8$.

Answer (score 0):

- Place the $0$ digit, but not first (no leading $0$) or last (not odd), with $2$ possibilities
- Choose an odd digit for the last place, with $2$ possibilities
- Place the $2$ digit in a remaining place, with $2$ possibilities
- Place the other odd digit in a remaining place, with $1$ possibility
- Multiply

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach.

Given any set of $k$ digits, including $0$ that are not to be repeated, the enumeration of how many $k$ digit numbers that can be formed is
$$k! - (k-1)!.\tag1$$

The second term expresses the elimination of $0$ as the leftmost digit.

In the present problem, the rightmost digit can be either $1$ or $3$.

Assume, without loss of generality, that it is $3$, complete the enumeration under that assumption, and then multiply the result by $2$, to reflect that the rightmost digit might also be $1$.

With $3$ as the rightmost digit, you then have $(4-1)$ digits remaining, including $0$.  Then employ equation (1) above, with $k=3$.

Therefore, the final enumeration is

$$2 \times [(3!) - (2!)].$$

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the answer is (2)(2)(1)(2) is because

- First digit: Cannot be 0, so there are three remaining numbers 1,2,3. But you must reserve one number (1 or 3) for the last digit, so there are actually **two** possible numbers to choose for the first digit.
- Second digit: Once you have chosen a number for the first digit, you can now choose the number 0 and some different number than first digit also keeping in mind that another number (1 or 3) is reserved for the last digit. So there are **two** possible numbers to choose for the second digit.
- Third digit: Only **one** possible number for the third digit.
- Fourth digit: **Two** possible numbers for the fourth digit (1 or 3).

Using the product rule gives (2)(2)(1)(2).

An easier method is $4!-2(3!)-4=8$ where

- $4!$ is the total number of ways to arrange $0123$
- $2(3!)$ is the total number of ways to have the last digit of the number as $0$ or $2$
- $3!-2=4$ is the total number of ways to have the first digit of the number as $0$ excluding two cases where the number contains $2$ as the last digit